# Angular6 basic video chat with dynamic session and token Id

Tags: angular, typescript, opentok

I have integrated the Basic video chat with https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples/tree/master/Angular-Basic-Video-Chat

Here the in `Angular-Basic-Video-Chat\src\config.ts` >> We need to mention the session and token Id.

In my page the `session id and token id` values are returned from firebase. So the values are dynamic. If so I passed the values to service as argument. But the publisher streams and subscribers are not working after changing this.

```
this.opentokconfigmodel.API_KEY = 'xxxxxxx';
            this.opentokconfigmodel.SESSION_ID = this.meetingsessionid;
            this.opentokconfigmodel.TOKEN = this.meetingtokenid;

this.opentokService.initSession(this.opentokconfigmodel).then((session: OT.Session) => {
  this.session = session;
  this.session.on('streamCreated', (event) => {

    this.streams.push(event.stream);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  });
  this.session.on('streamDestroyed', (event) => {
    const idx = this.streams.indexOf(event.stream);
    if (idx > -1) {
      this.streams.splice(idx, 1);
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
  });
})
.then(() => this.opentokService.connect())
.catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
  alert('Unable to connect. Make sure you have updated the config.ts file with your OpenTok details.');
});
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The sample app has 2 different ways of loading the credentials. One way is to hard code the values in the config.json file. The other way is to specify a URL to load the data from. If you have a look at opentok.service.ts you can see where it is handling these cases differently.

In your case I would replace this logic completely with the logic to load the data from Firebase. So instead of doing a fetch, use the Firebase API to load the apiKey, sessionId and token and then return the session object. Make sure you return a Promise in the initSession function. So something like:

```
initSession() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   // Do your firebase stuff to download the data
   this.session = this.getOT().initSession(firebase.apiKey, firebase.sessionId);
   this.token = firebase.token;
   resolve(this.session);
 });
}
```

I'm not sure what the Firebase API looks like, it probably already returns a Promise so you might not need to wrap this all in a Promise.